# Refering to a button then config it

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Okay, the problem Im having is that I do not understand how to refer to that particular button that was pressed. Im doing a game, if the use clicks a button I wanna know which X and Y coordinate it had. So, if you have a grid of buttons and you click one I want the coordinates and then I will change that button's color. :)

PROBLEM: Knowing which button was pressed in a grid.

Thanks in advance!

```
def matris():
    for i in range(5):
            newButton = Button(app, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "blue",command = lambda i=i: function(i))
            newButton.grid(row = i, column = 0)

    for i in range(5):
            newButton = Button(app, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "blue",command = lambda i=i + 5: function(i))
            newButton.grid(row = i, column = 1)

    for i in range(5):
            newButton = Button(app, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "blue",command = lambda i=i + 10: function(i))
            newButton.grid(row = i, column = 2)

    for i in range(5):
            newButton = Button(app, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "blue",command = lambda i=i + 15: function(i))
            newButton.grid(row = i, column = 3)

    for i in range(5):
            newButton = Button(app, width = 4, height = 2, bg = "blue",command = lambda i=i + 20: function(i))
            newButton.grid(row = i, column = 4)


def function(i):
    if button 23 was clicked.changeColor to e.g "blue"
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with `command = lambda i=i + 20: function(i)`? I don't think that's valid python syntax.

Comment: This seems to be partly pseudocode. Is this what you've actually written?

Comment: @Kevin: it's perfectly fine python code, why do you think it's wrong? Admittedly, it might be written a little clearer as `lambda widget_number=i+20: function(widget_number)`, but it's valid either way.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I was not familiar with a lambda expression where anything other than comma-separated variable names go between `lambda` and `:`. At first glance it looked like the OP wanted to increment `i` by some amount and then call `function`; on second glance, I guess the `= i + 20` is not assignment, but a default value.

Comment: @Kevin: yes, it's a default value.

Comment: if button 23 was clicked.changeColor to e.g "blue" is obviously not real code but pseudocode. :)

I solved the "problem" by using the value of i as the parameter which helped me determine which button was pressed. I gave each button a number, 0 to 24. 

But the really question still remains. I wanna make a grid of buttons, say 10x10. I want to know which one was clicked, some kind of reference so I can say "You got pressed, change color!".

How that made it any clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading all the comments and edits, it looks like what you really want to know is "which button was clicked?" when using the same command for multiple buttons.

The easiest way to do that is to pass some sort of unique identifier to the command associated with the widget. The most straight-forward way is to pass a reference to the widget itself, though that requires a two step process.

For example:

```
this_button = Button(...)
this_button.configure(command=lambda button=this_button: do_something(button))

def do_something(button):
    print "you clicked this button:", button
```

You can also use `functools.partial` to get the same result if you find lambda hard to wrap your head around:

```
this_button.configure(command=functools.partial(do_something, this_button)
```

If you prefer to create your button in a single step instead of two, you need some way to identify it. For me, the easiest way is with a dictionary. For example, if you're creating rows and columns of buttons, you could do this:

```
button = {}
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(10):
        button[r,c] = Button(..., command=lambda row=r, column=c: do_something(row, ccolumn))

def do_something(row, column):
    print "you clicked button", button[row,column]
```

Comment: The last example you gave is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to each button if you want to modify that button later. Since your numbering scheme is sequential you can use a list:

```
newButton = Button(...)
buttons.append(newButton)
...
def function(i):
    widget = buttons[i-1] # -1, because list indexes are zero-based
    if i == 23:
        widget.configure(background="blue")
```

If you're creating a grid of buttons and the buttons are otherwise identical, you might want to consider a simpler structure such as:

```
for row in range(5):
    for column in range(5):
        ...
```

It becomes instantly clear that you're creating five rows of five columns, whereas with your original code it takes several seconds of study to come to the same conclusion.

Comment: I did kind of that way by letting each button get an indiviual value of i and then telling them apart with that. But I still thinks its too much code for something that could be so simple. Thank for your answer btw!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the `command` argument, use the `bind` method to set a callback for `<Button-1>`. When Tkinter calls your callback, it will pass in an event object, which contains the widget that raised the event.

```
from Tkinter import *

def buttonClicked(e):
    e.widget["bg"] = "red"

root = Tk()

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        newButton = Button(root, width=10, height=2, bg="blue")
        newButton.bind("<Button-1>", buttonClicked)
        newButton.grid(row=y, column=x)

root.mainloop()
```

Edit: suppose you want to treat buttons differently depending upon their position in the grid. The simplest way to do this is to use a global dictionary to associate each button with its coordinate.

```
from Tkinter import *

coords = {}

def buttonClicked(e):
    x,y = coords[e.widget]
    print "{},{} clicked".format(x,y)
    if x == 4 and y == 3:
        e.widget["bg"] = "red"

root = Tk()

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        newButton = Button(root, width=10, height=2, bg="blue")
        newButton.bind("<Button-1>", buttonClicked)
        newButton.grid(row=y, column=x)
        coords[newButton] = (x,y)

root.mainloop()
```

In general, however, having a variable at the global scope isn't a good idea. It may be worth the effort to group all of your grid-based code into a single class, so none of its details leak out to the rest of the program.

```
from Tkinter import *

class ButtonGrid:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.coords = {}
        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                newButton = Button(root, width=10, height=2, bg="blue")
                newButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.buttonClicked)
                newButton.grid(row=y, column=x)
                self.coords[newButton] = (x,y)

    def buttonClicked(self, e):
        x,y = self.coords[e.widget]
        print "{},{} clicked".format(x,y)
        if x == 4 and y == 3:
            e.widget["bg"] = "red"

root = Tk()
b = ButtonGrid(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If you prefer functional over object-oriented, here's an alternative. Use the `command` option as you did in your original code, but use the [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function to specify ahead of time which variables ought to be passed to the function.

```
from Tkinter import *
import functools

def buttonClicked(widget, x, y):
    print "{},{} clicked".format(x,y)
    if x == 4 and y == 3:
        widget["bg"] = "red"

root = Tk()

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        newButton = Button(root, width=10, height=2, bg="blue")
        newButton["command"] = functools.partial(buttonClicked, newButton, x, y) 
        newButton.grid(row=y, column=x)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thats awesome! The problem is that I do not know how to tell which button was clicked. I only want some buttons to turn red, like "if e.widget has x = 4 and y = 3". Thanks for answering btw!

Comment: Well, by my interpretation it resolves his initial problem. That being, to paraphrase: "when the user clicks a button, change that button's color". I'll add some detail to address his revised requirements in a moment.